# How to filter Axios get results

Tags: search, filter, axios

I have a search bar set up, and what i am trying to do is that when you search for something it will do an axios get call, it will filter through all the results and give you only what you are searching for.

```
axios.get("api/blogs/" + this.state.pageIndex + "/10").then(res => {
  res.filter(function(author) {
    return author.firstName === this.state.query;
  });
});
```

I am using react.

Comment: What is your expected output and what is wrong with what you have now?

Comment: I suppose you _must be_ getting `this.state is undefined`, is that correct?

Comment: Because the [_javascript context_](https://git.io/fh8m2) inside `res.filter(...)` is not the _react object_, i.e. `this` doesn't point to the _react object_ and so you can't access `this.state`

Comment: `res.filter(function(author) {` change to `res.filter((author) => {` use arrow function

Answer (score 0):

@Just code thank you! I managed to figure it out but for whoever else has this same problem the arrow function will fix your problem. Obviously just having a search ajax call would be much better but this is a way around not having one, or if your search ajax call is broken